# Pelican doesn't generate the page

Tags: pelican

I cannot add simple page to the website using Pelican. I want to add the `/about` page.

My pelicanconf.py

```
AUTHOR = 'Aga'
SITENAME = 'MyPage'
SITEURL = ''

PATH = 'content'

TIMEZONE = 'GB'

DEFAULT_LANG = 'en'

# Feed generation is usually not desired when developing
FEED_ALL_ATOM = None
CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM = None
TRANSLATION_FEED_ATOM = None
AUTHOR_FEED_ATOM = None
AUTHOR_FEED_RSS = None

DEFAULT_PAGINATION = False
DEFAULT_DATE = 'fs'

THEME = 'themes/simple'

# Uncomment following line if you want document-relative URLs when developing
RELATIVE_URLS = True
CSS_FILE = "main.css"

PAGE_PATHS = ['']
PAGE_URL = '{slug}/'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = '{slug}/index.html'
```

I have `content/about.md` with one line (`Title: About`), `content/about.md.meta` specifying template (`Template: about`) and template added to the theme: `themes/simple/templates/about.html`. The About page is not generated and not shown in the output folder. The index page works fine (although consists of a template only - uses base.html and adds index.html in `content` block). Does anyone here know Pelican and can figure out what is wrong? This is super frustrating.

I use `pelican content` to generate the content and `pelican --listen` to preview the website.